# closing client socket and keeping server socket active

Tags: c, sockets

I am establishing a server-client connection using TCP sockets. Whenever I close the client socket my server is also closed. But I want only my client to be closed and my server must wait for next `accept()`.

Server side:

```
{
bind(lfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
listen(lfd, 10);
   while(1)
   {
        cfd = accept(lfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
   //server must wait here after client closes the connection application code
        close(lfd);
    }
}
```

client side:

```
inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &serv_addr.sin_addr);
connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
// ... application code
if(c == 1)
   close(fd);
```

Comment: Find multithreaded/multiconnection example for TCP sockets and see how to do it. E.g. in Codeproject.com

Comment: The trick is to fork off a new process to handle the new connection. Then continue running the main process while your child process runs the query to completion. If you use threads for this (and you can) then you need to make sure that the threads don't close each others sockets - since threads share the same heap.

Answer (score 15):

When you `accept` server side, you generate a new socket for that client only.

When you have finished dealing with the client you *must* `close()` that socket, (that's `close(cfd)` in your terminology). You *may* also `shutdown()` the socket - that will influence how the socket is closed at a TCP level. But whether you do or do not do a `shutdown()`, you *must* `close()` it, else you will leak FDs.

You must not `close()` your listen fd (`lfd` in your program) until you intend not to accept any more connections.

TLDR: change `close(lfd)` to `close(cfd)`

Answer (score 6):

The TCP listening socket described by the descriptor `lfd` is used for waiting for TCP incoming connections at a specific port. After the call of `accept`a new socket descriptor is created, the `cfd` in your example.

All the data exchange between server and client is performed using the `cfd`. If the client first close the socket, a possible `send` or `recv` at the server side, will return -1 with the appropriate `errno` value.

If you want the server to close the connection, you should use `shutdown(cfd, SHUT_RDWR)` and `close(cfd)` after,  NOT `close(lfd)`. This lets the `lfd` socket open, allowing the server to wait at the `accept` for the next incoming connection. The `lfd` should close at the termination of the server.

The `shutdown()` provides more flexibility, to send or receive remaining data prior the permanent termination of the communication.

Comment: You mean `shutdown` (not `close`)?.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. But close() will work too. The basic difference is that shutdown allows you to receive any pending data, whereas with close(), the socket is destroyed immediately.

Comment: BTW, you made a typo (`close`, not *clode*)

Comment: @Manos I don't think that's right. If you `shutdown` but don't `close`, you will leak an FD. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

accept call would return new socket descriptor (cfd in your code) that is connected to the client side, so when client closes its end of connection cfd will be closed and not lfd. You can use lfd (listening socket) for accepting connection as long as server needs. Also consider invoking shutdown before close(fd) in client code.