# C/Unix sockets: Server closes right after one client does

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

(this question is a sequel to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813120/c-unix-sockets-segmentation-fault-core-dumbed-due-to-char-pointer) dreadful question)

I've managed to work things out with my broken code and got it to work for multiple clients using threads.

Server:

```
#define SOCK_PATH "avg_socket"

int numofclients=0;
int numofrequests=0;
pthread_mutex_t MUT=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *find_average (void *arg)
{
        int so = (int) arg;
        int done;

        printf("Connected.\n");

            done = 0;

            do {
                int i=0;
                int numofelements=0;
                int sum=0;
                float avg;

               ...
               ...
               ...


                pthread_mutex_lock(&MUT);
                        numofrequests++;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&MUT);

                printf("\n\nNumber of requests: %d \n", numofrequests);
                printf("Number of clients: %d \n", numofclients);    

            } while (!done);

         close(so);
         pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
    {
        int s, s2, i, t, len;
        struct sockaddr_un local, remote;
        pthread_t thread[50];

        if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("socket");
            exit(1);
        }

        local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
        strcpy(local.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
        unlink(local.sun_path);
        len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);
        if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len) == -1) {
            perror("bind");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (listen(s, 5) == -1) {
            perror("listen");
            exit(1);
        }

        i=0;

        for(;;) {
            printf("Waiting for a connection...\n");
            t = sizeof(remote);
            if ((s2 = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, &t)) == -1) {
                perror("accept");
                exit(1);
            }
            numofclients++; //counting the number of clients
            pthread_create(&(thread[i++]), NULL, find_average, (void *)s2);
         }

        return 0;
    }
```

Client:

```
#define SOCK_PATH "avg_socket"

    int main(void)
    {
        int i, s, t, len, done;

        struct sockaddr_un remote;

        if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("socket");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Trying to connect...\n");

        remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
        strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
        len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);
        if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len) == -1) {
            perror("connect");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Connected.\n");

        done = 0;
        int yesorno=1;

        do {
            float avg;
            char seq[100];
            char str[100];
            char avgstring[200];


            printf("Give the sequence of integers: \n");
            fgets(seq, 100, stdin);

            ...
            ...
            ...

            printf("\nWanna Continue? (1/0) :");
            scanf("%d", &yesorno);
            getchar();

            if(!yesorno)
                done=1;

         } while (!done);

        close(s);

        return 0;
    }
```

(full codes [here](https://justpaste.it/16wkw) for anyone interested)

But now, every time I close the connection from one client, server closes too.

[image]

As seen above, client 3 closes the connection with the server, and the server itself closes simultaneously, instead of waiting for a connection or a client request.

It seems, to me, that there is something off about `close(so)` at server. I tried to move it inside the loop a la [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798419/closing-client-socket-and-keeping-server-socket-active), but this only made an infinite loop at the server.

So the question is, how do I keep a multithreading server active when a client closes?

Comment: I recommend to use a debugger, to trace the code to learn what is really going on.

Comment: For the two corner cases of `recv()` failing (Which malke it return `-1` or returning `100` this code `int checkresponse=recv(s, str, 100, 0);
            str[checkresponse]='\0';` writes out of `str`'s bounds, and doing so invoke the infamous Undefined Behaviour. Anything can happen from then on. You want to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

```
            char arr[100];
            recv(so, arr, 100, 0);

            int *array;    
            array=(int *)calloc(1, 100);

            char *p=strtok(arr, " ");
```

The `strtok` function requires a string as its first parameter. An arbitrary collection of bytes received over a network connection is not a string.

In a related problem, you throw away the result of `recv`. So you have no way to know when you've failed. Worse, if you succeed, you have no idea how many bytes you received! How are you expecting `strtok` to know? Magic?

Comment: Really not sure if this is really an insightful observation or a nitpick for not using an `if` for the `recv` and casting  `arr`.

Comment: Using an 'if' for the recv is also incorrect.  The value returned by recv() MUST be handled correctly and completely, (as should all system calls, but recv is in a class of its own).

Comment: I'm afraid that failure to understand, and correctly handle, the streaming nature of TCP is endemic in C TCP questions, as is the misuse of C library calls that require char arrays with a NUL terminator.  David is not 'nitpicking', and the value returned by recv() is the ONLY way to be sure how many bytes have been received, (if any).

Comment: @Coursal Overruning the receive buffer because you treated it as a string is a common cause of crashes and quite likely to be what's causing his crash. Another possibility is that he's running out of memory and derferencing a NULL return from `calloc` because he spins in a loop that allocates when the connection closes. All of that comes down to the problem I explained.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz please correct me if I misunderstood, you suggest to check the `recv()` for the `arr` collection of bytes and then turn `arr` to a string?

Comment: The usual method is to write your own "receive a message" function that calls `recv` as many times as necessary, accumulates the data in a buffer, and then turns that into a string. Also, sanely handle getting a -1 or 0 return value.